# Why does Linux redirect command (>)sometimes outputs a file started with Binary NULL(\00) sequence?

Tags: php, linux, cron

This problem happens when i use cron job of godaddy web hosting.

My cron job command like below(… Omits my private path):

> /usr/local/bin/php -q /…/Command.php >/…/log.txt;

In the Command.php i use echo to log.

But, sometimes some echo contents are replaced by binary \00 sequence as in the the log.txt:

[image: image description here]